# add nodes to a tree in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Defined in Scheme one (sumanodos-pareja-tree tree) function that takes a tree 
generic and returns a new generic tree where each datum is a pair containing the data 
Original (left) and the sum of its children nodes (right):

I do this:

```
(define (sumanodos-pareja-tree tree)
  (let ((bosque-sumados (map sumanodos-pareja-tree (hijos-tree tree))))
    (make-tree (cons (dato-tree tree) (suma-datos-raiz bosque-sumados))
               bosque-sumados)))

(define (suma-datos-raiz bosque-sumados)
  (if (null? bosque-sumados) 0
      (let ((primer-arbol (car bosque-sumados)))
        (+ (car (dato-tree primer-arbol))
           (cdr (dato-tree primer-arbol))                
           (suma-datos-raiz (cdr bosque-sumados))))))

(define tree22 '(2 (7 (1 (10) (4))
                    (5))
                 (6 (2 (3)))
                 (4)))

(sumanodos-pareja-tree tree22)
```

But it returns this error;

```
cons: second argument must be a list, but received 2 and 42
```

as I can do?

Comment: Is this a learning language? Try replacing 'cons' with 'list'  in the code above.

Comment: Fine, added it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a restriction of some Racket learning languages. Use `list` instead of `cons`.